# Why do I get this compiler error?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I want to understand this error: **syntax error before 'bool'**, on the following code:

```
typedef struct hdate{
    date_arc_u  date;
    unsigned short  time;
    bool test;
}PACKED_ST horodate_a
```

When I change bool to another type there is no error.
I already use bool in others parts of the code without error.

***I don't understand this error here ....***

Comment: Can u post some more code. One problem may be due to "}PACKED_ST horodate_a", you are typedef and creating the new variable at the same time.

Comment: Let me guess.. C90?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably because you are writing C code, and the `bool` type does not exist in C. Your file extension is probably .c, not .cpp, and your code definitely looks like it was written in C.

Comment: Thanks ,I did not notice that there was some file with c extension. I changed it and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your C compiler doesn´t know about bool type.

You can try:

1- Including this at first `#include <stdbool.h>`

2- Declaring at first `typedef enum bool { false, true };`

Comment: 2 is not a good solution at all. The reason `stdbool` was added is to prevent the compatibility nightmare when everyone defines their own.

Comment: Thanks but I was using cpp (except for this file which was with a c extension)